# Cayley digraphs of a group

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, order-theory, cayley-graphs

I could not find an answer to the questions online.
How many loopless Cayley digraphs of a group G there are? 
How many loopless Cayley graphs of a group G there are if |G| = n and G has i self-inverse elements?
Could someone advise a literature regarding this topic or explain an answer?

**My thoughts about it**

The answer to the first question is $2^{|G|-1}$, since its the number of the subsets not containing identity elements.
The answer to the second question is $2^{({n-i}/2)+i}$ since if the element is not self-inverse element we pair them up and either include both or none, so its ${n-i}/2$ and $+i$ since I elements are self inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix a finite group $G$, a Cayley di/graph $\Gamma = \Gamma(G, S)$ depends only on a generating set $S$ of $G$.  What you missed is $S$ must *generates* the whole group $G$, as in the definition of the Cayley di/graph.

A loop in a Cayley di/graph $\Gamma$ corresponds to the identity $1 \in S$. 
So your first question asks the number of generating sets $S$ of $G$ with $1 \not\in S$. (This equals the half of the number of generating sets of $G$.) It sounds hard problem and I don't know the answer. Anyway, it must not be $2^{\lvert G \rvert - 1}$ in general.

Your second question sounds just wrong. It doesn't make sense to me. Why involutions (self-inverses) matter?

Comment: I don't think that you are right, cause for digraphs we only need the condition that identity is not included in set S.

Comment: and for second question, it matters because elements are not self inverse we need to include either both of them or non.

Comment: @Orat Different people use different definitions. In my area, it's not uncommon to allow $S$ not to generate $G$, in which case the (di)graph is disconnected.

Comment: @MariyaKav I think you should point to the book/article that contains the definition of the Cayley digraphs and the Cayley graphs you use or spell out by yourself. Different definitions lead to different answers.